# I want to apply script to multiple subsheet in one Sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I followed youtube instruction and copied this script

```
var SHEET_NAME = 'Sheet1';
var DATETIME_HEADER = '입력일시';
function getDatetimeCol(){
  var headers = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME).getDataRange().getValues().shift();
  var colindex = headers.indexOf(DATETIME_HEADER);
  return colindex+1;
}
function onEdit(e) {  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = ss.getActiveCell();
  var datecell = ss.getRange(cell.getRowIndex(), getDatetimeCol());
  if (ss.getName() == SHEET_NAME && cell.getColumn() == 1 && !cell.isBlank() && datecell.isBlank()) {      
    datecell.setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
  }
};
```

I want to apply this script to all subsheet in the file.

so I tried to add more sheet name like

```
var SHEET_NAME = 'Sheet1'; => var SHEET_NAME = ['Sheet1','Sheet2','Sheet3',]
```

or

```
var SHEET_NAME = 'Sheet1';
var SHEET_NAME = 'Sheet2';
var SHEET_NAME = 'Sheet3';
```

and they didn' work.

I don't have any, even rudimentary knowledge to this area, could you teach me how can I apply this script on whole subsheet, please?

Comment: You are right to use an array, but try to do it this way: `var SHEET_NAME = ['Sheet1','Sheet2','Sheet3']` and use this method to check `SHEET_NAME.includes(ss.getName())`

Comment: Thanks for answer.
can you tell me where I have to put    SHEET_NAME.includes(ss.getName())  this?
I tried to do it myself but failed.

Comment: in the condition of the if statement `... if (SHEET_NAME.includes(ss.getName()) && cell.getColumn() == ... `

Comment: I changed them like this

    var SHEET_NAME = ['Sheet1','Sheet2','Sheet3'];

and

      if (SHEET_NAME.includes(ss.getName()) && cell.getColumn() == 1 && !cell.isBlank() && datecell.isBlank()) {      
    datecell.setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");


and start.
there's error 
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'getDataRange' of null

maybe I can't understand or follow your guidence because I don't know anything about code...
I try to fix rest of them. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed your code slightly according to the task at hand:

```
SHEET_NAMES = ['Sheet1','Sheet2','Sheet3'];
DATETIME_HEADER = '입력일시';

function onEdit(e) {  
  let range = e.range,
      sheet = range.getSheet();
 
  if (SHEET_NAMES.includes(sheet.getName()) && range.rowStart > 1 && range.columnStart == 1 && !e.value == '') { 
    let colindex = sheet.getDataRange().getValues().shift().indexOf(DATETIME_HEADER)+1,
        datecell = sheet.getRange(range.rowStart,colindex);
    if (datecell.isBlank()) datecell.setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
  }
};
```

I don't think it's a good idea to run `getDatetimeCol()` every time you make a change in the table - it's better to do it only when the changes occur in the right sheets and cells

Comment: I found answer

var SHEET_NAME = ["10", "11", "12", "13", "복사용"];

function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if( s.getName() == "10" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
    var r = s.getActiveCell();
    if( r.getColumn() == 1 ) { //checks the column
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 19);
      if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //is empty?
        nextCell.setNumberFormat("MM/dd HH:mm:ss")
        nextCell.setValue(new Date());
    }
  }

and add same 11,12,13..sheet after that.
I need to change some code

Comment: everytime I add more sheet or move cell, but It's working anyway.

and I will try yours right now.
Thanks for your help, Sergey!